# How can I programmatically restrict node access?

Tags: 8, nodes

I'm using Drupal 8 with the nodeaccess module.

I'm able to set the node grants with the form.

I also have a custom module which imports new nodes. These new nodes should be shown only to certain users.

I know I can insert the corresponding lines into the database tables nodeaccess and node_access. But this might be not consistent.

Is there a way to set the nodeaccess programmatically?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I restrict user access to view nodes based on field value?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/229395/how-can-i-restrict-user-access-to-view-nodes-based-on-field-value)

Comment: Nodes created through the API should have any system grants applied automatically. How are you importing nodfes into the system?

Comment: I'm importing an Excel file and create a node. After creating the node I use a function to build the database rows in node_access and nodeaccess.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I control node access based on entity reference to multiple users](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/313780/how-can-i-control-node-access-based-on-entity-reference-to-multiple-users)

Answer (score 0):

I use a function to build the database rows in node_access and nodeaccess:

```
  private function set_node_access($nid, $id, $realm='nodeaccess_uid', $view=1, $update=0, $delete=0)
  {
    // ksm("nid: $nid uid: $uid");
    $connection = \Drupal::database();
    $sql = "INSERT INTO nodeaccess (nid, gid, realm, grant_view, grant_update, grant_delete) 
            VALUES($nid,$id,'$realm',$view,$update,$delete) 
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE grant_view=VALUES(grant_view), grant_update=VALUES(grant_update), grant_delete=VALUES(grant_delete)";
    $connection->query($sql);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO node_access(nid, langcode, fallback, gid, realm, grant_view, grant_update, grant_delete) 
            VALUES($nid,'de', 1, $id,'$realm',$view,$update,$delete) 
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE grant_view=VALUES(grant_view), grant_update=VALUES(grant_update), grant_delete=VALUES(grant_delete);";
    $connection->query($sql);
  }
```

That's not the nice way, but it works for me.

Comment: This only prevents access viewing a single node on its canonical URL but not when viewing it in views or entity lists. For that you need a different strategy: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/52756/views-search-ignoring-custom-node-access-permissions